# What is the fastest way to obtain frequencies of integers in a vector?

Tags: r, histogram, frequency, ecdf

Is there a simple and fast way to obtain the frequency of each integer that occurs in a vector of integers in **R**?

Here are my attempts so far:

```
x <- floor(runif(1000000)*1000)

print('*** using TABLE:')
system.time(as.data.frame(table(x)))

print('*** using HIST:')
system.time(hist(x,breaks=min(x):(max(x)+1),plot=FALSE,right=FALSE))

print('*** using SORT')
system.time({cdf<-cbind(sort(x),seq_along(x)); cdf<-cdf[!duplicated(cdf[,1]),2]; c(cdf[-1],length(x)+1)-cdf})

print('*** using ECDF')
system.time({i<-min(x):max(x); cdf<-ecdf(x)(i)*length(x); cdf-c(0,cdf[-length(i)])})

print('*** counting in loop')
system.time({h<-rep(0,max(x)+1);for(i in seq_along(x)){h[x[i]]<-h[x[i]]+1}; h})

#print('*** vectorized summation') #This uses too much memory if x is large
#system.time(colSums(matrix(rbind(min(x):max(x))[rep(1,length(x)),]==x,ncol=max(x)-min(x)+1)))

#Note: There are some fail cases in some of the above methods that need patching if, for example, there is a chance that some integer bins are unoccupied
```

and here are the results:

```
[1] "*** using TABLE:"
   user  system elapsed 
   1.26    0.03    1.29 
[1] "*** using HIST:"
   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.00    0.10 
[1] "*** using SORT"
   user  system elapsed 
   0.22    0.02    0.23 
[1] "*** using ECDF"
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.00    0.17 
[1] "*** counting in loop"
   user  system elapsed 
   3.12    0.00    3.12
```

As you can see `table` is ridiculously slow and `hist` seems to be the fastest. But `hist` (as I am using it) is working on arbitrarily-specifiable breakpoints, whereas I simply want to bin integers. Isn't there a way to trade that flexibility for better performance?

In **C**, `for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)h[x[i]]++;` would be blisteringly fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest is to use `tabulate` but it requires positive integers as input, so you have to do a quick monotonic transformation.

```
set.seed(21)
x <- as.integer(runif(1e6)*1000)
system.time({
  adj <- 1L - min(x)
  y <- setNames(tabulate(x+adj), sort(unique(x)))
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget you can inline C++ code in R.

```
library(inline)

src <- '
Rcpp::NumericVector xa(a);
int n_xa = xa.size();
int test = max(xa);
Rcpp::NumericVector xab(test);
for (int i = 0; i < n_xa; i++)
xab[xa[i]-1]++;
return xab;
'
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(a = "numeric"),src, plugin = "Rcpp")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think tabulate or the C++ versions are the way to go but here's some code using rbenchmark which is a great package for looking at timings (I added a few slower function tests too):

```
######################
### ---Clean Up--- ###
######################

rm(list = ls())
gc()

######################
### ---Packages--- ###
#####################

require(parallel) 
require(data.table)
require(rbenchmark)
require(inline)


#######################
### ---Functions--- ###
#######################

# Competitor functions by Breyal
Breyal.using_datatable <- function(x) {DT <- data.table(x = x, weight = 1, key = "x"); DT[, length(weight), by = x]}
Breyal.using_lapply_1c_eq <- function(x = sort(x)) { lapply(unique(x), function(u) sum(x == u)) } # 1 core
Breyal.using_mclapply_8c_eq <- function(x = sort(x)) { mclapply(unique(x), function(u) sum(x == u), mc.cores = 8L) } # 8 cores

# Competitor functions by tennenrishin
tennenrishin.using_table <- function(x) as.data.frame(table(x))
tennenrishin.using_hist <- function(x) hist(x,breaks=min(x):(max(x)+1),plot=FALSE,right=FALSE)
tennenrishin.using_sort <- function(x) {cdf<-cbind(sort(x),seq_along(x)); cdf<-cdf[!duplicated(cdf[,1]),2]; c(cdf[-1],length(x)+1)-cdf}
tennenrishin.using_ecdf <- function(x) {i<-min(x):max(x); cdf<-ecdf(x)(i)*length(x); cdf-c(0,cdf[-length(i)])}
tennenrishin.using_counting_loop <- function(x) {h<-rep(0,max(x)+1);for(i in seq_along(x)){h[x[i]]<-h[x[i]]+1}; h}

# Competitor function by Ulrich
Ulrich.using_tabulate <- function(x) {
  adj <- 1L - min(x)
  y <- setNames(tabulate(x+adj), sort(unique(x)))
  return(y)
}

# I couldn't get the Joe's C++ version to work (my laptop won't install inline) butI suspect that would be the fastest solution

##################
### ---Data--- ###
##################

# Set seed so results are reproducable
set.seed(21)

# Data vector
x <- floor(runif(1000000)*1000)


#####################
### ---Timings--- ###
#####################

# Benchmarks using Ubuntu 13.04 x64 with 8GB RAM and i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
benchmark(replications = 5,
          tennenrishin.using_table(x),
          tennenrishin.using_hist(x),
          tennenrishin.using_sort(x),
          tennenrishin.using_ecdf(x),
          tennenrishin.using_counting_loop(x),
          Ulrich.using_tabulate(x),
          Breyal.using_datatable(x),
          Breyal.using_lapply_1c_eq(x),
          Breyal.using_mclapply_8c_eq(x),
          order = "relative")
```

Which results in the following timings

```
                                 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
6            Ulrich.using_tabulate(x)            5   0.176    1.000     0.176    0.000       0.00     0.000
2          tennenrishin.using_hist(x)            5   0.468    2.659     0.468    0.000       0.00     0.000
3          tennenrishin.using_sort(x)            5   0.687    3.903     0.688    0.000       0.00     0.000
4          tennenrishin.using_ecdf(x)            5   0.749    4.256     0.748    0.000       0.00     0.000
7           Breyal.using_datatable(x)            5   2.960   16.818     2.960    0.000       0.00     0.000
1         tennenrishin.using_table(x)            5   4.651   26.426     4.596    0.052       0.00     0.000
9      Breyal.using_mclapply_8c_eq(x)            5  10.817   61.460     0.140    1.196      54.62     7.112
5 tennenrishin.using_counting_loop(x)            5  10.922   62.057    10.912    0.000       0.00     0.000
8        Breyal.using_lapply_1c_eq(x)            5  36.807  209.131    36.768    0.000       0.00     0.000
```

Comment: inline can be a bit of a pain to get working. On Windows you need the [rtools package](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), but I'm not sure about Ubuntu. I ran your tests with my code and it comfortably won, 4 times quicker than the tabulate solution.